# How to correctly restore factory condition on ACER laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (dual-boot). Ubuntu is great but Windows is showing some problems: I'd like to just restore Windows as it was the first day **without** touching my ubuntu installation whatsoever

Do you know if it's possible?

- I have the rescue disks made with Acer eRecovery Management the day I bought the PC
- I don't have any other windows disk to just re-install it
- I know I'll probably have to re-install GRUB, but that's not my problem right now
- The factory restore partition sits untouched on my hard-drive since day 1
- please don't tell me to just remove windows -> not an option

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible as far as I know when you do a restore windows will wipe out ubuntu and you will have to reinstall it but you could clone ubuntu using clonezilla so you will be able to put ubuntu right back on without losing important files or settings and it is fast and easy to put ubuntu back on your computer using clonezilla.

[clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/downloads.php)

Comment: Hi wild man, good to see you here

Comment: @bodhi.zazen hello good to be here and good to see you!!!